# Understanding the construction of Exterior Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

**Background**

The tensor space of type $(r,s)$ associated with $V$ is the vector space $$\underbrace{V\otimes \ldots \otimes V}_{\text{r copies}} \otimes \underbrace{V^* \otimes \ldots \otimes V^*}_{\text{s copies}}.$$

The *tensor algebra* of $V$ is the direct sum $T(V)=\sum_{r,s} V_{r,s}$ for $r,s \geq 0.$

Let $C(V)$ be the subalgebra $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} V_{k,0}$ of $T(V)$. Let $I(V)$ denote the two sided ideal in $C(V)$ generated by the set of elements of the form $v \otimes v,$ where $v \in V$ and set $$I_k(V)=I(V) \cap V_{k,0}.$$

The *exterior algebra* $\Lambda(V)$ is the graded algebra $C(V)/I(V)$. If we set $$\Lambda_k(V)=V_{k,0}/I_k(V)$$ for $k \geq 2$ and $\Lambda_0(V)=\mathbb{R}, \ \Lambda_1(V)=V$ then $$\Lambda(V)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Lambda_k(V).$$

Denote multiplication in the algebra $\Lambda(V)$ by $\wedge$

**Questions**

I know very little abstract algebra so a lot of this construction is strange to me. I have the following questions:

1. What is the point of doing the intersection $I(V) \cap V_{k,0}$ when
       defining $I_k(V)$?
2. Why is the exterior algebra graded? Here is what I attempted to do:

   > Let $u \in \Lambda_k(V)$ and $v \in \Lambda_l(V)$ We should show that $u       \wedge v \in \Lambda_{k+l}.$ I **think** $u \in \Lambda_k$
   >   means that $u$ is the equivalence class $u+I_{k}(V)$ and similarly
   >   $v$ is the equivalence class $v+I_{l}(V).$ I also **think** that $u
   >     \wedge v$ corresponds to the equivalence class of $u \otimes v$ in
   >   (**I don't know what space**).

As you can see, my understanding of this construction is very weak. I think if I see $2$ clearly I will understand how to work with the exterior algebra. To keep this question unambiguous, please consider my attempt with question $2$ above and try to explain, explicitly, what an element in $\Lambda_n(V)$ looks like (and how I can see this from the construction above) and also to explain what $u \wedge v$ means in terms of the quotient construction.

Comment: 1. You can define the algebra $\Lambda\left(V\right)$ straight away as the quotient $T\left(V\right) / I\left(V\right)$; then you don't need to define $I_k\left(V\right)$. But this way you get $\Lambda\left(V\right)$ merely as an algebra, not as a graded algebra. You can still define the grading as an afterthought, but the author of the approach wanted to get it right at the beginning, whence the introduction of $I_k\left(V\right)$.

Comment: 2. You are thinking right. The space you don't know is $V_{k+l}$.

Comment: Note: The standard notations for $V_{k,0}$ and $\Lambda_k\left(V\right)$ are $V^{\otimes k}$ and $\wedge^k V$.

Comment: An element in $\Lambda_k\left(V\right) = \wedge^k V$ is defined as a congruence class of elements in $V_{k,0} = V^{\otimes k}$ modulo the vector subspace $I_k\left(V\right)$. For instance, if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are two elements of $V$, then the tensors $x \otimes y \otimes z$ and $-y \otimes x \otimes z$ in $V_{3,0}$ are congruent modulo $I_3\left(V\right)$, since their difference is $x \otimes y \otimes z - \left(-y \otimes x \otimes z\right) = \left(x + y\right) \otimes \left(x + y\right) \otimes z - x \otimes x \otimes z - y \otimes y \otimes z \in I_3\left(V\right)$

Comment: ... (in fact, this difference is a linear combination of pure tensors with two equal adjacent tensorands). Hence, the projections of $x \otimes y \otimes z$ and $-y \otimes x \otimes z$ on $\wedge^3\left(V\right)$ are equal. I have chosen two pure tensors to keep this example simple, but of course not every tensor is pure, so there are more complicated examples.

Comment: It is easy to see by induction (do the proof to get familiar with these spaces) that the projection of a pure tensor $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n \in V^{\otimes n}$ onto $\wedge^n V$ (where $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n \in V$) is actually $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n$ (where, to be fully precise, the $v_i$ in $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n$ are the projections of the $v_i \in V^{\otimes 1}$ onto $\wedge^1 V$; but this projection is an isomorphism). Thus, every element of $\wedge^n V$ will be a linear combination of such $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank-you for the insightful response. I am currently working through them to gain a better understanding of the material but first I have the following question: What is the reason behind the space being $V_{l+k}$? My thought is that when multiplying in the quotient space we have $(u+I_k(V)) \otimes (v+I_l(V))=u \otimes v+ I_{k+l}(V)$. However, $u$ and $v$ are part of two different quotient spaces so is this multiplication defined in this way?

Comment: Specifically, quotient space multiplication normally works when we have two elements of the form $u+N$, $v+N$ and then the multiplication gives $uv+N$ (here I am using an arbitrary example of some quotient space that looks like $R/N$ where $R$ is a vector space and $N$ is a subspace. In our example though, $u$ and $v$ are in two different quotient spaces.

Comment: If $u \in V^{\otimes k}$ and $v \in V^{\otimes l}$, then $u \otimes v \in V^{\otimes \left(k+l\right)}$. This is not a particular case of your construction with $u+N$ and $v+N$, because here $u$ and $v$ are understood to live in two different spaces.

Comment: One thing that might be confusing you: An element of $\wedge^k V$ can be viewed either as an element of $V^{\otimes k} / I_k\left(V\right)$, or as an element of the bigger space $\wedge V = \Lambda\left(V\right) = T\left(V\right) / I\left(V\right)$. In the former case, it is a congruence class of an element of $V^{\otimes k}$ modulo $I_k\left(V\right)$; in the latter case, it is a congruence class of an element of $T\left(V\right)$ modulo $I\left(V\right)$. When you regard $u$ and $v$ in the latter fashion (i.e., as congruence classes of elements of $T\left(V\right)$), then ...

Comment: ... you indeed can multiply them by the rule $\left(u+N\right)\left(v+N\right) = uv+N$ (notice that $N$ here is $I\left(V\right)$). When you regard $u$ and $v$ in the former fashion, however, this pattern does not apply, since it would involve three different $N$'s. Instead, what you do is define their product by $\left(u+I_k\left(V\right)\right) \left(v + I_l\left(V\right)\right) = u \otimes v + I_{k+l}\left(V\right)$ (please don't put a tensor sign on the left hand side). This can also be seen as a special case of a general rule, but it's not as simple as "algebra modulo ideal".

Comment: @darijgrinberg So I am working out the induction to show that $v_1 \otimes  \ldots \otimes v_n=v \wedge \ldots \wedge v_n$ but I can't "get my hands on it (signaling that I still don't understand this). I understand what you mean when you say that $x \otimes y \otimes z $ is $-y \otimes x \otimes z$ because their difference falls in the same space but I think I do not know how to represent an element in $V^{\otimes^k}$ in the space $\Lambda_k(V)$. Here is my thinking:

Comment: If we consider two elements $v_1 \otimes v_2 \in V^{\otimes ^2}$ (rather than formally start the induction at one element) then passing to the quotient space $\Lambda_2(V)$, this element is of the form $a+I_2(V).$ Do I have to show that $a=v_1 \wedge v_2?$ I am sorry if this is cumbersome  (this my first exposure to this material so it is out of left field).

Comment: You should show that $v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n = v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n + I_n\left(V\right)$. But notice that the $v_i$ on the left hand side actually stand for $v_i + I_1\left(V\right)$.